# Why doesn't the "GetShortPathName" function sometimes gives me the short path?

Tags: c, winapi, dosbox

I am trying to use the [`GetShortPathName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getshortpathnamew) function to give me the short version of two paths, but it succeeds in only one path and fails in the other path.

```
// Get the game directory path
wchar_t GameDirPath[MAX_PATH] = L"\0";
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, GameDirPath);

// Get the engine directory path
wchar_t EngineDirPath[MAX_PATH] = L"\0";
wcscat(EngineDirPath, GameDirPath);
wcscat(EngineDirPath, L"\\Assets\\Engine\\");

// Get the short path of the engine directory
wchar_t EngineShortPath[MAX_PATH] = L"\0";
GetShortPathName(EngineDirPath, EngineShortPath, MAX_PATH);
```

The following gives me the correct short path:

`D:\Games\NEEDFO~1\Assets\Engine\`

But this one doesn't:

`D:\Games\FIFA 97\Assets\Engine\`

Note that the two examples exist in the same folder "Games".

---

In short:
I want to pass the path to "[DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/).exe" as a parameter but it doesn't accept the windows paths like this "D:\Games\FIFA 97\Assets\Engine", so you must convert it to a DOS path like this "D:\Games\FIFA97~1\Assets\Engine", so, I try to use the [`GetShortPathName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getshortpathnamew) function to do that mission.

---

Why does this problem happen, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Check the return value of `GetShortPathName` and tell us.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: it returns `31`.

Comment: That is the length of the returned value. So that IS the short path. My assumption (to be verified) is that, since the path is already shorter than a minimum amount of bytes, it doesn't need to be shortened.

Comment: There is only _one_ call to `GetShortPathName` in your code snippet, please show the actual code that reproduces the error, including the actual long and short paths

Comment: Incorrect. Both paths you show *are* short paths. You should re-read the documentation. A short-path contains directory names in 8.3 format. Your second path doesn't have any directories with a name longer than 8 characters, so it doesn't need to be modified. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#short-vs-long-names

Comment: @Jabberwocky: There are no errors that happened, it's just an unknown behavior.

Comment: *"I want to use those paths in "DOSBox" but you know it doesn't accept any paths containing spaces"* - If by *"DOSBox"* you meant *"command interpreter"* then that statement is wrong. It allows specifying path names that have spaces. They just need to be quoted.

Comment: The embedded space is a corner-case, DOS did not make it easy to create one.  The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) words it well: "disallowed by convention though not by the APIs".  Not the only DOS problem btw, I remember helping out somebody that created a file named "CON".

Comment: @HansPassant Not so bad. I remember somebody on a Unix machine creating a file called `*`. He wasn't happy when he attempted to delete it and found that everything went with it!!

Comment: @IInspectable: Please explain more about your idea. how can I convert a win path to a dos path like this "D:\Games\FIFA 97\Assets\Engine\" ? the dos version must be like this "D:\Games\FIFA97~1\Assets\Engine\" after conversion.

Comment: @LionKing e.g type `mkdir "Hello World"` in a command prompt. It will create a directory named `Hello World`. "Quoted" = between quotes.

Comment: You don't get to make the rules. If you pass `D:\Games\FIFA97~1\Assets\Engine` to anything that attempts to interpret that as a path, the system will fail to open that filesystem object, because there is no such object with that name. `8.3` refers purely to lengths, not characters allowed. It's not entirely clear what problem you are trying to solve here, but it much sounds like your solution isn't.

Comment: @IInspectable: I want to pass a path like this "D:\Games\FIFA 97\Assets\Engine\" to DOSBox but DOSBox doesn't accept paths like that, so you must convert that path to be a compatible DOS path like this "D:\Games\FIFA97~1\Assets\Engine". is that possible?

Comment: I've said this before: You don't get to make the rules. Obviously, you could translate any given path name into something that *you* believe to be the canonical short name. The system has its own rules, and if your understanding of what a short name is and what the system thinks a short name is disagree, the system wins, you lose. Now it's still wildly unclear what your actual problem is. Quoting paths that happen to contain spaces seems to be a solved problem. Does this not, for some obscure reason, work for DOSBox?

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getshortpathnamew) explicitly states:

> If the specified path is already in its short form and conversion is not needed, the function simply copies the specified path to the buffer specified by the `lpszShortPath` parameter.

The API behaves as documented. There's nothing that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Back to 90s, when DOS OS was largely used, files and directories names were limited to a maximum length of 8 characters (*8.3 format*; meaning 8 bytes for the file name and 3 for the file extension).

So `hello.txt` file was admitted, and `helloguys.txt` (9 chars log) was "illegal".

With Windows this limitation has beeen removed, and short names have been introduced in order to convert paths to *DOS compliant* format.

---

Now that we know what a *short path is*, we can analyze your case. In path

```
D:\Games\Fifa 97\Assets\Engine\
```

**every token is DOS compliant**. So what is the *short* version of this path? Well, the path itself. And that's why `GetShortPathName( )` returns an unchanged path.

You can find a wide description in [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#short-vs-long-names).

Comment: A bit of historic background on the [Long Filename Specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20181025124257/home.teleport.com/~brainy/lfn.htm). That's a wild read.

Comment: I believe `GetShortPathName()` returns an unchanged path also if 8.3 names are [disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name) on the volume. I couldn't find an explicit mention of this in the docs, but it would make sense.

Comment: @zett42 the best thing would be to verify it with a test program (something that, unfortunately, I cannot do at the moment).